# How can I modify my EBNF to handle cases like `- not 12`, `not + -1`

Tags: programming-languages, bnf, ebnf

I created EBNF for expressions below

```
<expression> ::= <or_operand> [ "or" <or_operand> ]

<or_operand> ::= <and_operand> [ "and" <and_operand> ]

<and_operand> ::= <equality_operand> [ ( "=" | "!=" ) <equality_operand> ]

<equality_operand> ::= <simple_expression> [ <relational_operator> <simple_expression> ]

<relational_op> ::= "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">="

<simple_expression> ::= <term> [ ( "+" | "-" ) <term> ]

<term> ::= <factor> [ ( "*" | "/" ) <factor> ]

<factor> ::= <literal>
           | "(" <expression> ")"
           | "not" <factor>
           | ( "+" | "-" ) <factor>

<literal> ::= <boolean_literal> | <number>

<boolean_literal> ::= "true" | "false"

<number> ::= <digit> [ <digit> ]

<digit> ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
```

My problem lies within the factor section

```
<factor> ::= <literal>
           | "(" <expression> ")"
           | "not" <factor>
           | ( "+" | "-" ) <factor>
```

You can see that I included three unary operators `not`, `-`, and `+`. They work for specific types like `not` only applies to boolean values only and `+`/`-` applies to numbers only.

I don't know how to handle cases when `not` is mixed with `+`/`-` like `not +7`, `- not true`, etc. for example. Is there any way I can modify the grammar so `not` can never be mixed with `+`/`-`?

Will it suffice?

```
<factor> ::= <literal>
           | "(" <expression> ")"
           | ( "not" | ( "+" | "-" ) ) <factor>
```

Or maybe it's parser's job to solve this issue?

Comment: It's the (semantic) parser's job to solve this issue, and you can read more about the difference between syntactic and semantic parsing in questions and answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678079).  To put it simply: syntax→structure, semantics→meaning.  The fact that `true` is a Boolean value does not matter during syntax analysis; it's just a <factor> like `1` or `-7`. Semantic analysis is what determines `- 7` is a non-Boolean value and says that `not  - 7` is invalid because `not` cannot apply to a non-Boolean value like `- 7`.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy  to solve. You have two different styles of expressions each with their own syntax, so you just do not mix them, and keep their syntax rules separated.

A boolean expression can only occur in certain places, such as an assignment or some kind of choice statement. A numerical expression can only occur in a comparison or an assignment. This is not something that is handled at the semantic level, and if one looks at the grammar for many languages, this is how it is solved.

So you have for numeric expressions:

```
<simple_expression> ::= <term> [ ( "+" | "-" ) <term> ]

<term> ::= <factor> [ ( "*" | "/" ) <factor> ]

<factor> ::= <number>
           | "(" <expression> ")"
           | ( "+" | "-" ) <factor>

<number> ::= <digit> [ <digit> ]

<digit> ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
```

This is now self contained. We can now build this into boolean expressions:

```
<boolean_expression> ::= "not" <boolean_expression>
                      | <logical_expression>
                      
<logical_expression> ::= <or_operand> [ "or" <or_operand> ]

<or_operand> ::= <and_operand> [ "and" <and_operand> ]

<and_operand> ::= <equality_operand> [ ( "=" | "!=" ) <equality_operand> ]
               
<equality_operand> ::= <simple_expression> [ <relational_operator> <simple_expression> ]
                 | <boolean_literal>

<relational_op> ::= "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">="

<boolean_literal> ::= "true" | "false"
```

Notice that I permitted the equality comparison of boolean literals, however if you did not want to permit this you could change the rules to only permit them for an and operand.

Now we can use these in another rule, such as assignment:

```
<assignment> ::= <variable> ":=" ( <simple_expression> | <boolean_expression> )
```

All is done.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't notice until now. Anyway, thanks for the answer! This is an interesting approach, I didn't think of that before. But I think there's one problem: using the assignment rule you created below, I'm not sure how a parser can determine if it's a simple expression or a boolean expression? Any ideas?

Comment: @RaySiplao Most parsing algorithms would have no trouble with that.